# Reading cycle time on a TwinCAT 3 PLC

Tags: plc, twincat

Is there a way for a PLC program to know its own cycle time?

As a workaround, I can just add a persistent variable or a constant to tell it manually, but that's obviously error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TwinCAT3 this is available in [PlcTaskSystemInfo](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/globaldatatypes/714821259.html&id=1449094368155551069) (variable `CycleTime`).
Combine it with the FB [GETCURTASKINDEX](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/27021597795180939.html&id=) to get the data you want.

See one example (though not cycle-time, but still same FB) here [at AllTwinCAT](https://alltwincat.com/2017/11/05/first-cycle/).

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jakob's answer - you can also use `GETCURTASKINDEXEX` function ([Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/31018507.html&id=103554021675037415)) instead of `GETCURTASKINDEX` FB. This way you don't have to instantiate it.

```
_TaskInfo[GETCURTASKINDEXEX()].CycleTime
```

Will return cycle time as multiples of 100ns (UDINT)

```
UDINT_TO_LREAL(_TaskInfo[GETCURTASKINDEXEX()].CycleTime) / 10_000_000
```

Will return cycle time as seconds (LREAL)

Comment: Nice. I also didn't know that you could use `_` as a thousand separator. If I remember correctly I once tried it, but then it didn't work. Now I tried it and it indeed works. Not sure what I did wrong last time. Anyway TIL thanks :D.

Comment: Same for me, they must have added it one day. I like this feature in python, so I kept trying every now and then :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly an answer to your question, but can be used to determine the Cycle time.

I like to use the `Time()` function. It returns a value of data type `TIME`. It does not represent an absolute time, but can be used to calculate the time between two calls to `Time()`. In this way you can calculate the Cycle time.

I use it in function blocks (FB) where timing is critical. In this way the FB knows when it was lastly called instead of assuming that it is being run each scan. Even if I or another user of my FB "forgets" to call the FB each scan, the FB still delivers correct outputs.

You can find info on `Time()` using this [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529365899.html?id=5740953758704593015). There is also a function called `LTime()` which returns a value of data type `LTIME`, but it seems that Beckhoff did not bother to document this function.

Comment: I like the dependability aspect. Unfortunately, requires at least two cycles to calculate the difference. If this is an issue, the method could maybe be combined with PlcTaskSystemInfo from other answers.

Comment: @Mikkel you can link directly to Infosys page by right clicking the "Functions" link and selecting "Copy link address" (or similar, if you are using browser different than Chrome).